# HTML and JQuery check if username and password are correct?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a basic session log (without using PHP) that checks if both the username and password are correct. It has worked with only the password, but I can't make it check the username, The code is as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#psword').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && this.value == "abcd" && ("#uname").value == "1234") {
      $(".login").fadeOut("fast", function() {});
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="login" id="uname" type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
<input class="login" id="psword" type="text" placeholder="Password" required>
```

It works up until I add the ("#uname").value part. How must I change it?

Comment: I think you're missing a `$` in front of ("#uname"). Try this: `$("#uname")`.

Comment: @DerekHopper Already did, looked like this: if(e.keyCode==13&&this.value=="abcd"&& $("#uname").value=="1234") but it didn't work

Comment: `$("#uname")` is a jQuery object, which uses the `val()` method to retrieve the value, whereas `value` is a property of a DOM object, and accessed viat `DOMNodeReference.value`. From jQuery you could use: `$("#uname")[0].value`, but I can't imagine why you'd want to, in the DOM you could use `document.querySelector("#uname").value` or `document.getElementById('uname').value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `("#uname").value` which should have a `$` in the start and a `.val()` in the end instead of `value` which isn't recognized in jquery but core javascript so change it to the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#psword').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && this.value == "abcd" && $("#uname").val() == "1234") {
      $(".login").fadeOut("fast", function() {});
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="login" id="uname" type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
<input class="login" id="psword" type="text" placeholder="Password" required>
```